# Various calculations on GPA using a collection of students and their respective GPA's

Tags: c++, arrays, compiler-errors, user-defined-functions

To give a lot more detail on the question I am working on here is the exact assignment:

Write a program that calculates that average, minimum, maximum and
average GPA for all students. First, your program will read in the student records
(names and GPAs) and determine the number of student records in the file. After all
of the names and GPAs are obtained, your program will sort the student GPAs and
names in ascending order of GPA. Finally, your program will, 1) display all names
and GPAs, 2) determine and display the minimum and maximum GPAs (with
corresponding student names), and 3) calculate and display the average GPA.

**Here is what I have as a finished product:**

```
//gpaCalc.cc                                                                                                                                                                                   
//Author: O'Brien Little                                                                                                                                                                       
//Purpose: To calculate and display the average, minimum and maximum GPA for some U of L students, where the GPA's and student names are read from
//an input file and are stored as arrays 
//Inputs: GPA's of several students, student names                                                                                                                                                          
//Outputs: Average, minimum and maximum GPA of the collection of students, along with the corresponding student names
//and display a list of all students and their respective GPA's
//Assumptions: Max 50 Students' information

#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

const int arraySize=50; //Upper limit on the number of students and GPA's

//Function prototypes
void obtainNamesAndGPAs(double GPA[], string name[], int &students);
void sortGPA(double GPA[], string name[], int students);
void displayMinMaxGPA(const double GPA[], const string name[], int students);
double calcAvgGPA(const double GPA[], int students);



int main()
{
    //Variable declarations
    double AvgGPA;
    int index=0, students;

    //Reading the names of the students and their corresponding GPAs and storing them in an array
    obtainNamesAndGPAs;

    //Sorting the students GPAs in assending order allong with the corresponding student names
    sortGPA;

    //Displaying all the names of the students and their GPAs
    cout << "Here is a list of all the students and their GPAs that were entered into te system: " << endl;

    //While loop to display all the students and their GPAs
    while(index<students)
    {
        cout << name[index] << GPA[index];
        index++;
    }

    //Displaying the lowest and the highest GPAs and the students that achieved those
    displayMinMaxGPA;

    //Calculating the average GPA of the collection
    AvgGPA = calcAvgGPA;

    //Displaying the average GPA to the user
    cout << "The average GPA of the collection of students was: " << AvgGPA << endl;

    //End program
    return 0;
}

//****************************************************************                                                                                                                             
//Function: obtainNamesAndGPAs                                                                                                                                                                        
//Purpose: To obtain the names and GPAs of the students                                                                                                                                
//Input: GPA[], name[], &students                                                                                                                                                             
//Return Value: Void                                                                                                                                                                           
//Assumtions: None                                                                                                                                            
//****************************************************************  
void obtainNamesAndGPAs(double GPA[], string name[], int &students)
{
    //Array access variable
    int indexn=0, indexg=0; 

    //File stream declaration
    ifstream inFile;

    //Opening the input file and read in the first value
    inFile.open("GPA.txt");
    inFile >> name[indexn];

    //While loop to gather the GPAs from the file and insert them into their corresponding array index
    while(!inFile.eof() && indexn < arraySize)
    {
        indexn++;
        inFile >> GPA[indexg];
        indexg++;
        inFile >> name[indexn];
        students++;
    }
    //End of function
    return;
}

//****************************************************************                                                                                                                             
//Function: sortGPA                                                                                                                                                                       
//Purpose: To sort students (and thier corresponding GPAs 
//in assending order
//Input: GPA[], name[], students                                                                                                                                                            
//Return Value: Void                                                                                                                                                                           
//Assumtions: None                                                                                                                                            
//****************************************************************  
void sortGPA(double GPA[], string name[], int students)
{
    //Variable declarations
    double temporaryg;
    int first, second;
    string temporaryn;

    //Sorting the GPAs by asscending order
    //For loop to indicate the first value of the GPA array
    for(first=0;first<students;first++)
    {       
        //For loop to indicate the following value in the GPA array to check 
        for(second=first+1;second<students;second++)
        {
            //If statement to make sure the GPA and name array are in asscending order and 
            //ensures the student name stays with the GPA
            if(GPA[first]>GPA[second])
            {
                //Storing the bigger GPA and name for later
                temporaryg=GPA[first];
                temporaryn=name[first];
                //Making it so the smaller GPA and name comes first
                GPA[first]=GPA[second];
                name[first]=name[second];
                //Making the lower GPA and name come second
                GPA[second]=temporaryg;
                name[second]=temporaryn;
            }
        }
    }

    //End of function
    return;
}

//****************************************************************                                                                                                                             
//Function: displayMinMaxGPA                                                                                                                                                                      
//Purpose: To display the Min and Max GPA and their students
//Input: GPA[], name[], students                                                                                                                                                            
//Return Value: Void                                                                                                                                                                           
//Assumtions: None                                                                                                                                            
//**************************************************************** 
void displayMinMaxGPA(const double GPA[], const string name[], int students)
{
    //Variable declaration
    //initialized to extreme values to ensure they will be taken by the array values
    double Maxg=0, Ming=10;
    int index;
    string Maxn, Minn;

    //For loop to find the Max and Min GPA in the array and find the corresponding 
    //students name
    for(index=0;index<students;index++)
    {
        if(GPA[index]>Maxg)
        {
            Maxg=GPA[index];
            Maxn=name[index];
        }
        else if(GPA[index]<Ming)
        {
            Ming=GPA[index];
            Minn=name[index];
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    //Displaying the Min and Max GPA and the corresponding students to the user
    cout << "The minimum GPA that was entered belonged to: " << Ming << " and was: " << Minn << endl;
    cout << "The maximum GPA that was entered belonged to: " << Maxg << " and was: " << Maxg << endl;

    //End of function
    return;
}

//****************************************************************                                                                                                                             
//Function: calcAvgGPA                                                                                                                                                                   
//Purpose: To calculate the average GPA
//Input: GPA[], students                                                                                                                                                            
//Return Value: AvgGPA                                                                                                                                                                           
//Assumtions: None                                                                                                                                            
//**************************************************************** 
double calcAvgGPA(const double GPA[], int students)
{
    //Variable declarations
    double sum, AvgGPA;
    //Index set to zero to make sure the array starts in the first position
    int index=0;

    //While loop to take each individual GPA out of the array and add it to sum
    while(index<students)
    {
        sum = sum + GPA[index];
        index++;
    }

    //Calculating the average GPA
    AvgGPA = sum/students;


    //End of function and return AvgGPA
    return AvgGPA;
}
```

**However, I am receiving the following errors an am unable to problem solve these on my own:**

*In function 'int main()':*

- 32:23: warning: statement is a reference, not call, to function
  'obtainNamesAndGPAs' [-Waddress]**Solved`**
- 32:23: warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]**Solved`**
- 35:12: warning: statement is a reference, not call, to function
  'sortGPA' [-Waddress]**Solved`**
- 35:12: warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]**Solved`**
- 43:17: error: 'name' was not declared in this scope
- 43:32: error: 'GPA' was not declared in this scope
- 48:21: warning: statement is a reference, not call, to function
  'displayMinMaxGPA' [-Waddress]**Solved`**
- 48:21: warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]**Solved`**
- 51:12: error: cannot convert 'double(const double*, int)' to 'double'
  in assignment**Solved``**

**Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance**

*"`" errors were solved by calling the function and putting the parameters in*

*"``" errors were solved by putting parameters in brackets after calling the calcAvgGPA function*

Comment: You need to add parentheses to actually call a function `sortGPA()`. Along with actually passing the argument required for that function `sortGPA(GPA, name, students);`

Comment: Thank you, that helped with the majority of the errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few big errors here in basic understanding. Lets go through them and see what we can help enlighten on. Also, You're using std::string but not using `std::vector` (which would make this overall assignment easier).

Also(2) **disclaimer**, I haven't looked at the logic in any of the functions to see if they'd work correctly... once this builds for you, you can work on getting the logic correct if its wrong.

1. Fix the errors that CoryKramer mentions (which you've edited your question to suggest you have)
2. you're not declaring the GPA or name objects in the main function

   - Since you're not using classes and do not have any member data, you need to store this information in the `main` scope.
3. Your functions do not take references to their parameters, you are taking them by copy

---

#### Not declaring variables

```
    //Displaying all the names of the students and their GPAs
    cout << "Here is a list of all the students and their GPAs that were entered into te system: " << endl;

    //While loop to display all the students and their GPAs
    while(index<students)
    {
        cout << name[index] << GPA[index];  // <--- This line
        index++;
    }
```

The above mentioned line is trying to reference 2 variables that do not exist in this scope (or global scope). You need to declare these variables in `main`'s scope. If you don't have these variables available in a scope where they can be edited, the different functions won't be able the same variables.

---

#### Taking items by copy versus by reference

```
//Function prototypes
void obtainNamesAndGPAs(double GPA[], string name[], int &students);
```

In this prototype, you're taking the parameter `students` by reference which means that variable in `main` scope could be updated. But you're not taking any of the other parameters by reference but by copy. Notice the missing `&`? Even if you had those variables in the `main` scope, they wouldn't get updated as the functions make copies and uses those copies in their scopes instead of modifying the variable in a higher scope.
All of your functions essentially have this error.
Think about what the functions need for input and what variables need to be modified versus ones that don't.

---

#### Also

I have a feeling you're going to hit larger issues with dynamic array sizes. I can see this because I see no `new` instances for `GPA` or `name` variables. This is where a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) would really shine but I'll leave that up to you to complete (as this is a homework assignment).

Comment: Thank you, your advice really helped and I rewrote my code keeping these in mind and have progressed much farther